# Is there away to change the background color to my button when I hover over it, and when I hover off it, it returns to normal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]

When I hover over my button I want to change the color, then when I hover away from the button it goes back to normal.

Here is my code

```
<Button
  outline
  color="secondary"
  style={{
    marginLeft: 5, borderRadius: '5px', padding: '2px', background: '#E3E3E3', color: '#000',
    fontSize: 7, marginTop: 0
  }}
  onClick={() => { handleCopy(player) }}
>
  <span className="enhanced-sports enhanced-sports-copy4" />
</Button>
```

Is there a way to fix this issue? Maybe add `transition : 0.1s ease-in-out`

Comment: Try adding `outline: 'none'` to your `style` object

Comment: When I hover over my button, I want to change the color of it when hover on it, then when I hover away from the button, it goes back to normal

Answer (score 0):

The outline is coming from the browser defaults that ensure accessibility. Someone who is using a keyboard to navigate uses the `outline` to be able to see what is focused.

However, by default in browsers, it also shows if you click and not just if you use keyboard navigation.

Many answers will tell you to disable focus outlines altogether but that is bad for accessibility and so a bad idea. You can disable them for mouse users only by adding this to your stylesheet:

```
:focus:not(:focus-visible) { outline: none }
```

This way users tabbing through your elements will still see it, which is necessary for accessibility reasons.

Comment: When I hover over my button, I want to change the color of it when hover on it, then when I hover away from the button, it goes back to normal

Comment: Your edited question is somewhat different but I will try to help. What library is `Button` from?

Comment: import { Button} from 'reactstrap'

Comment: Unfortunately the only way with `reactstrap` (which is quite rudimentary sadly) is to add a `className` to this `Button` and then add global styles in your CSS using a `:hover` declaration. You could combine `reactstrap` with something like `styled-components` if you wanted to do it in the component file.

Answer (score 0):

modify your style object in <Button>

```js
style={{
    marginLeft: 5, 
    borderRadius: '5px', 
    ......, // others style
    outline: 'none'
}}
```